# Simplifying a Rational Number using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, greatest-common-divisor

I'm working on question in python which deals with rational numbers, and it has a method which simplifies it. For example `12/8` gives `3/2`. I have done that question and getting the correct answer also but I have done by finding gcd of the numerator and denominator. May someone help doing it using some inbuilt special python features or functions, modules or anything unique to python as you say "The Pythonic way!"

Is there such a way or any test cases should be included to cover all possibilities?

Here is my code:

```
class RationalNumber:
def __init__(self, n, d=1):
    self.n=n
    self.d=d

'''def gcd(self, a, b): // I have taken out gcd by two methods: recursion and while loop
    if b>a:
        t=a
        a=b
        b=t

    while a%b != 0:
        r=a%b
        a=b
        b=r

    return b
    '''

def gcd(self, a, b):
    if a%b==0:
        return b
    else:
        return self.gcd(b, a%b)

def simplify(self):
    x=self.gcd(self.n, self.d)
    self.n=self.n/x
    self.d=self.d/x

    return RationalNumber(self.n, self.d)

def __str__(self):
    print "%s/%s"%(self.n, self.d)

r1 = RationalNumber(12,8)
print r1.simplify()
```

When I run the program it gives the answer and gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\CTE Python Practise\New folder\RationalNumberSimplify.py", line 42, in <module>
    print r1.simplify()
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

Please help me removing the error and improving the code and making it more pythonic!

Comment: All the functions are inside class sorry for wrong indentation

Comment: You should use spaces for indentation, not tabs

Comment: While you have a legitimate question here, the point of this site is NOT to " improving the code", "help in making the program more efficient". Check over the FAQ and next time ask a single pointed question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fraction module mentioned by @stranac. As for your other question about your error, it can be fixed by replacing the method `__str__` with

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "%s/%s"%(self.n, self.d)
```

For either, `__str__` or `__repr__` you'll need to return a string **not** simply print it out. It may be helpful to look over the question:

[Difference between __str__ and __repr__ in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python)

Comment: Even when I have changed str() function to:                                def __repr__(self):
   print "%s/%s"%(self.n, self.d)                                       then also I get the same error, what is mistake am I doing ?? please help??

Comment: Note the difference - I call **return** you call **print**. A `__str__` or `__repr__` method _has to return something_!

Answer (score 5):

There is a more pythonic way for doing this.

The [fractions module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html) has a gcd() function, but you most likely won't need it since the Fraction class should do everything you want.

```
>>> import fractions
>>> print fractions.Fraction(12, 18)
2/3
```

Comment: Not that I know of, and the docs don't seem to mention anything